# Codeigniter Fatal error: Call to undefined method Pagination::initialize()

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to user the Codeigniter pagination and I receive the following error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Pagination::initialize()".

**I found a few post with the same issue but they all stated the solution is to auto load the Pagination class which I am already doing**. The only issue I can think of is that my class uses custom controller "MY_Controller" which extends the CI controller. Below is my code, please help. Thanks in advance.

MY_Controller.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->init();
}

}
```

Main Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends MY_Controller {

function index()
{
    $this->display();   
}

function display()
{
//pagination settings
$config['base_url']    = base_url();
$config['total_rows']  = 200;
$config['per_page']    = 50;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
}
}
```

Comment: Load inside the display function $this->load->library('pagination');

Comment: Any success plz share

Answer (score 1):

If you made a custom controller and extend it with core `My_Controller` than load pagination library inside the `display()` function:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
```

Comment: My original logic before I auto loaded was to load the library in the display method. I move the load back to the display method and I still receive the same error.

Comment: I resolved the issue by upgrading to Codeigniter 3.0.